# Jquery Ajax, How to Grab Specific Element(s) of Source Page

Tags: jquery, ajax

Trying to learn Ajax - jQuery through simple code samples I have this two html files as: index.html and source.html.the inex.html is as:

```
enter code here
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('button').click(function(){
   $.get('source.html', function(data) {
   $('.result').html(data);
   });
  });
 });
 </script>
 <title>Main Page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <button>Load Page</button>
 <div class="result"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

and the source.html as:

```
enter code here
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Source Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="test1">Hello Ajax!</div>
<div class="test2"> Again Hello Ajax!</div>
<div class="test1">WoW Ajax!</div>
 <p> The html() method sets or returns the content(innerHTML) of the selected... </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

now my question is how I can grab specific elements instead of getting all elements in the index page? For example , how I can filter the request object to just get all div with class "test1" or only

from the page source.I also do not really understand what does "data" parameter means in

```
enter code here
$.get('source.html', function(data) {
$('.result').html(data);
```

can you please let me know what does it mean?

data from Console:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Main Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="test">Hello world!</div>
<div class="test1">Hello Ajax!</div>
<div class="test2"> Again Hello Ajax!</div>
<div class="test1">WoW Ajax!</div>
<p> The html() method sets or returns the content (innerHTML) of the selected   elements.When this method is used to return content, it returns the content of the FIRST   matched element. When this method is used to set content, it overwrites the content of ALL matched elements.</p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: but it is working on my machine

Answer (score 1):

After getting the response of your ajax call, you can find elements in the following way:

```
$.get('source.html', function(data) {
   test1_elements = $(data).find('.test1')
});
```

`test1_elements` will now contains all the elements with class `test1` from your source.html.

Comment: Hi HungryCoder thanks for your comment but this is not returning anything to page I modify the code to `code` $.get('source.html', function(data) {
   test1_elements = $(data).find('.test1')                                   $('.result').html(test1_elements);
});`code` but it doesnt retrun anything to index page

Comment: check in console to see what you actually got.  ` test1_elements = $(data).find('.test1') ; console.log(test1_elements)`

Comment: Ok I am just getting [] @ line 11.

Comment: well, then check whole `data` using `console.log(data)`

Comment: are you getting html that matches to source.html? post it somewhere.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19593/discussion-between-hungrycoder-and-behseini)

Answer (score 0):

You can grab specific elements by their id or class:

```
var $byids= $('#id');
var $byclass= $('.class');
```

The data parameter in the function contains the entire response data, that is what source.html shows.

You can use

```
var $div= $(data).find('#divid');
```

to select stuff from the data.

Updated:
You have 2 test1 elements.
The following will get the html of each, and stitch it together.
The last line displays the summary in all elements with class "test" in the document.

```
$.get('source.html', function(data) {
    var $test1_elements = $(data).find('.test1');
    var summary= '';
    $test1_elements.each({function(){ summary+= $(this).html(); });
    $('.test').html(summary);
});
```

Comment: hi adder but how I can use var $byids= $('#id'); inside the $.get()?